# Math.round troubles

Tags: java, rounding

I want to round to two decimal points so naturally I'd use:

```
Double number = Math.round(number*100.0)/100.0
```

But I ended up getting really long outputs, with lots of decimal points. So I tried different inputs for Math.round() similar to the ones I need to use and found that

```
Math.round(8.3391700279483738E17) = 833917002794837376
Math.round(8.3391700279483738E17 * 100) / 100.0 = 9.223372036854776E16
```

Does this make sense to anyone?

Comment: The entire technique is invalid. Floating-point values don't have decimal places. They have binary places, which are incommensurable with decimal places, so you can't round them to specific numbers of decimal places. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12684082/207421) for proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be correct

Math.round(8.3391700279483738E17) = 833917002794837376

makes sense as 8.3391700279483738E17 mathematically means 8.3391700279483738 * 10^17 or

8339170027948373800 and not a decimal number. The small marginal difference is due to Delta error.